# Can I use model validation/validation attributes for initializing an object in non-ASP projects?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, initialization

I came across this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for model validation and found validation attributes pretty amazing. But it looks very geared towards the web and I believe it only works when deserializing.

What would be the equivalent/idiomatic way to validate objects when initializing and throughout the object's lifetime? Or maybe *I can* use validation attributes but just couldn't find the non-ASP docs?

Comment: _"and I believe it only works when deserializing"_ - one important detail - not when deserializing, but binding.

Comment: If you don't mind using a different approach from attributes, you can use for example FluentValidation (not affiliated, that's just what I know and happily use), where you can use `.Validate(subject)` pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Validator.TryValidateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=net-6.0) with manually created  [`ValidationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext?view=net-7.0):

```cs
var someObjectToValidate = ...;
var vc = new ValidationContext(someObjectToValidate, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(u, vc, results, true);
```

But personally I prefer using [FluentValidation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) package which can be [integrated](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html) with ASP.NET Core.